# OPEN JPA - @TableGenerator with negative values running in infinate loop

Tags: openjpa

```
@TableGenerator(name = "ParticipantGen", schema = "sa", table = "ADP_TBL_OID", pkColumnName = "TYPE_ID", pkColumnValue = "5321", valueColumnName = "OBJ_NUM", allocationSize = 50)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ParticipantGen")
    private BigInteger objid;
```

I have a configuration like above to generate the primary key for a table.
The next value for the key is a negative number. 
When I run the flow, Somehow the JPA is not accepting -ve numbers and running in infinite loop to get a positive number. 
Because of this the application is blocking since the db thread to insert table record is not released.

Would be great if somebody can help here.

```
Log:
302378  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> [0 ms] spent
302378  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> executing prepstmnt 277699 UPDATE SA.ADP_TBL_OID SET OBJ_NUM = ? WHERE TYPE_ID = ? AND OBJ_NUM = ? [params=(long) -2116596711, (String) 5321, (long) -2116596761]
302378  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> [0 ms] spent
302379  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> executing prepstmnt 277700 SELECT OBJ_NUM FROM SA.ADP_TBL_OID WHERE TYPE_ID = ? FOR UPDATE [params=(String) 5321]
302379  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> [0 ms] spent
302379  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> executing prepstmnt 277702 UPDATE SA.ADP_TBL_OID SET OBJ_NUM = ? WHERE TYPE_ID = ? AND OBJ_NUM = ? [params=(long) -2116596661, (String) 5321, (long) -2116596711]
302380  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> [1 ms] spent
302380  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> executing prepstmnt 277703 SELECT OBJ_NUM FROM SA.ADP_TBL_OID WHERE TYPE_ID = ? FOR UPDATE [params=(String) 5321]
302381  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> [1 ms] spent
302381  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> executing prepstmnt 277705 UPDATE SA.ADP_TBL_OID SET OBJ_NUM = ? WHERE TYPE_ID = ? AND OBJ_NUM = ? [params=(long) -2116596611, (String) 5321, (long) -2116596661]
302381  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> [0 ms] spent
302381  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> executing prepstmnt 277706 SELECT OBJ_NUM FROM SA.ADP_TBL_OID WHERE TYPE_ID = ? FOR UPDATE [params=(String) 5321]
302382  openjpa  TRACE  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t -1257420086, conn 73905> [1 ms] spent
```